# Proving a random walk with a drift is recurrent

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk

Given the following set of independent random variables $\mathbb{P}(X_n=1)=\frac{1+n^{-\beta}}{2}, \mathbb{P}(X_n=-1)=\frac{1-n^{-\beta}}{2}$ and the sum $S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}X_n$ I managed to prove that if $\beta<0.5$ then $S_n$ is transient by using Hoeffding's bound and that if $\beta > 1$ $S_n$ is recurrent by treating the random variables as a simple random walk with a drift - which I proved is finite almost surely.

I am now trying to prove the case of $0.5\leq\beta\leq1$. I am pretty sure intuitively that it is recurrent however I am not successful in proving the case.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way to prove this is to use the Lindeberg central limit theorem.  Let $m_1=2$, $m_2$, $m_3$, $\dots$ be a sequence of positive integers with $m_{i+1}\ge m_i^2$ for all $i$, and let $T_i:=X_{m_i+1}+\cdots+X_{m_{i+1}}$.  To apply the Lindeberg CLT to $T_i$, the first step is to compute the mean
\begin{eqnarray*}\mu_i&:=&{\Bbb E}X_{m_i+1}+\cdots+{\Bbb E}X_{m_{i+1}}\\
&=&(m_i+1)^{-\beta}+\cdots+m_{i+1}^{-\beta}\\
&\le&\int_{m_i}^{m_{i+1}} x^{-\beta} \, d\beta\\
&=&\frac{1}{1-\beta}(m_{i+1}^{1-\beta}-m_i^{1-\beta})&\qquad&\hbox{(if $\beta<1$; $\log(m_{i+1}/m_i)$ if $\beta=1$)}\\
&=&O(m_{i+1}^{1-\beta})&\qquad&\hbox{(if $\beta<1$; $O(\log m_{i+1})$ if $\beta=1$)}\\
&=&O(m_{i+1}^{1/2})
\end{eqnarray*}
and the variance
$$\sigma_i^2:={\Bbb E}[(X_{m_i+1}-(m_i+1)^{-\beta})^2]
+\cdots+{\Bbb E}[(X_{m_{i+1}}-m_{i+1}^{-\beta})^2].$$
Since $m_i\ge 2$ and $\beta\ge \frac 1 2 $, each term $(X_j-j^{-\beta})^2$ in this sum is always between $(1-3^{-1/2})^2$ and $(1+3^{-1/2})^2$.  Therefore, $\sigma_i^2=\Theta(m_{i+1}-m_i)$, and since $m_{i+1}\ge m_i^2\ge 2 m_i$, we also have $\sigma_i^2=\Theta(m_{i+1})$ and so  $\sigma_i=\Theta(m_{i+1}^{1/2})$.

Now, the Lindeberg condition is that, for all fixed $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\sum_{m_i+1\le j\le m_{i+1}} \mathbb{E} \left[(X_j - j^{-\beta})^2 \cdot \mathbf{1}(| X_j - j^{-\beta} | \ge \epsilon \sigma_i ) \right]\qquad\qquad(*)
$$
approaches zero as $i$ becomes large, but
since $|X_j-j^{-\beta}|$ is bounded and $\sigma_i\to\infty$, for $i$ large enough, (*) will be zero.  This means that we can apply the Lindeberg CLT to find that
$(T_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i$ converges in distribution to a standard normal distribution.
Now, $$S_{m_{i+1}}=S_{m_i}+T_i \le T_i + m_i \le T_i + m_{i+1}^{1/2}$$ so
$${\Bbb P}(S_{m_{i+1}}\le 0\mid S_{m_i})\ge {\Bbb P}((T_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i\le (-m_{i+1}^{1/2}-\mu_i)/\sigma_i)$$
and, by our estimates on $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$, there are constants $K>0$ and $L>0$ so that, for all sufficiently large $i$,
$$
m_{i+1}^{1/2}+\mu_i\le K m_{i+1}^{1/2}, \qquad \qquad
\sigma_i\ge L m_{i+1}^{1/2},
$$
so for sufficiently large $i$,
$${\Bbb P}(S_{m_{i+1}}\le 0\mid S_{m_i})\ge {\Bbb P}((T_i-\mu_i)/\sigma_i\le -K/L)\qquad(**)$$
and, by convergence in distribution, the right-hand side of (**) approaches $\Phi(-K/L)$ as $i\to\infty$, so for sufficiently large $i$,
$${\Bbb P}(S_{m_{i+1}}\le 0\mid S_{m_i})\ge\frac{\Phi(-K/L)}{2}.$$
This proves that $S_n$ is almost surely nonpositive infinitely often.  Similarly, $S_n$ is almost surely nonnegative infinitely often, so $S_n$ is recurrent.

Comment: Thanks. I see in the mean why it will be $O(m_{i+1}\cdot(m_i+1)^{-\beta})$ but not why it would be $O(m_{i+1}\cdot m_{i+1}^{-\beta})=O(m_{i+1}^{1-\beta})$
Same goes for the variance being $\Theta(m_{i+1})$, why does that happen?

Comment: Why does $|X_i|$ being vounded imply it meets the criteria for the lindeberg condition?

Comment: Also, I am having trouble with the end given that lindeberg holds and from that CLT, why does the convergence in distribution bound the right hand side? Also, it needs to bounf it by a positive real number not by 0

Comment: I expanded my answer to try to explain these points more clearly.

Comment: Where did you find the lindeberg equation formulation you used?
I saw online:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sigma_{i}^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\left(T_{i}-\mu_{k}\right)^{2}\cdot1_{\left\{ \left|T_{k}-\mu_{k}\right|>\epsilon\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sigma_{j}^{2}}\right\} }\right]=0$

Also, the limit we receive is $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(T_{k}-\mu_{k}\right)}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sigma_{j}^{2}}}\overset{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}$ and not as written. What have I missed?

Comment: You need to use the form of the Lindeberg condition applicable to triangular arrays of random variables.  See for example section 10.2 in  [these lecture notes](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/pitman/s205f02/lecture10.pdf) or Theorem 27.2 in Billingsley's _Probability and Measure_ (3rd ed.), and keep in mind that the $X$'s are being normalized in different ways in these two places and in my answer.